# Importing adjacency matrix from file of 0/1 arrays

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, import

Is it possible to import adjacency matrix for graph representation, from simple text file with NxN (rows x columns) of 0s/1s:

```
0 1 0 0
1 0 1 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty much taken from the documentation of [`AdjacencyGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AdjacencyGraph.html)

```
data =
  "0 1 0 0
  1 0 1 1
  0 1 0 0
  0 1 0 0";
AdjacencyGraph[ImportString[data], VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: graph]